# Custom Infrared Code copy in android IR remote app

Tags: android, arduino, samsung-mobile, infrared

I have built a Infrared Receiver and transmitter using this sparkfun steps on Arduino like [this steps on sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ir-communication)

I can now receive the IR codes as well as transmit the IR Codes. The received IR is printed on serial monitor.

Serial Monitor Output
[image]

Now I want to send the same received IR code with Android device that supports IR like Samsung s5. I can not find any android app that could transfer these custom codes received on Arduino.

Comment: I too would like an app to send custom ir codes

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.binarymode.android.irplus

This app worked for me to send IR raw codes on my samsung s5.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.binarymode.android.irplus&hl=en&gl=US

according to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nB0GBuiQ_3g